# Azure IOTEdge-Gateway authentication error

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I've been trying to set up an IOTEdge Device as transparent gateway to forward leaf-telemetry to IOTHub via IOTEdge. I've followed and read through the steps in the official Azure documentations. I'm going to just summarize what it did

1. **Have a working IotEdgeDevice**
2. **Download the IotEdge Tools**(*for testing purposes only from the zip
   file*)
3. **Copy the hostname name from */etc/iotedge/config.yaml* (*from the host iotEdge Device*) and create certificates from certificates generation tool/bash-scripts provided for testing purposes**
4. **Move the Root-cert, intermediatte cert, and key to Iot-Edge-Device and set their absolute paths (*/home/user/certs/xxx.pem*) in the *config.yaml* at iotedge(/*etc/iotedge*/ )**
5. **Restart IotEdge with systemctl(because why not)**
6. **Copy the RootCA to Leaf-Device(*A rasberry pi in my case*)**
7. **I know I had to do EITHER of the two but i ended up doing both of these (*Point 8 and 9*)**
8. **Install Root.Ca in OS (Copying rootCA.pem file into */usr/local/share/ca-certificates/* ) then running *sudo update-ca-certificates*. At this point the TSL handshake command (*openssl s_client -connect*) was giving verified OK so I decided to directly to not mention/link the Root-CA via SDK- but I had the authentication failure already at this point.**
9. **Using Root-CA via a python SDK (example python program https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/device/samples/edge_downstream_client.py ). So at this point I have the working CA-cert installed in my OS and I have it linked via tha python-SDK too. Still it won't connect(PS the test command via bash returns Verified OK)**

*PS the hostname in connection string that I'm using in the leafDevice is an IP address(The DNS seem to be messing it up and the name given in config.yaml's host doesnt seem to be resolvable here even when from another device on network we can ping to that. So I just decided to mention the IP-address behind that hostname -belongs to IOTEdge). Also I had the IOTEdgeDevice set as the Parent Device of Leaf while creating it in portal and I had chosen the authentication to be symmetric to save myself all the manual X509 mess for testing purposes*

The errors I'm getting from the edgeHub container logs are multiple. I am listing a few of them

```
 - Error authenticating token for hmspi because the audience hostname
   192.168.100.14 does not match IoTHub hostname mps-hms.azure-devices.net or the EdgeHub hostname
   edgeuser-virtual-machine.
 - Client hmspi in device scope not authenticated locally.
2019-07-19 05:29:13.979 +00:00 [WRN] 
 - 0x05 not Authorized
```

It is to mention here that the time  in docker container(EdgeHub) is not the same as either that of EdgeDevice or LeafDevice(these two timeZones are same, set to GMT+5 while the docker container EdgeHub seems to have the timezone UTC- i think its the same as where the iotEdgeHub is located on Azure Servers- but I doubt it creates the problem since the bash test command with openSSL with certificates returns a "Verified Ok"). Any input would be HIGHLY appreciated as I seem to be stuck trying to fix this now.

**Update :**
**So I changed the connection string from shorter version 
**

```
HostName=myGatewayDevice;DeviceId=myDownstreamDevice;SharedAccessKey=xxxyyyzzz
```

to

```
HostName=myiothub.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=myDownstreamDevice;SharedAccessKey=xxxyyyzzz;GatewayHostName=myGatewayDevice
```

It does work now but I'm confused why it wouldn't since I already have a parent/child relation between EdgeDevice and my LeafDevice (as mentioned here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-authenticate-downstream-device you can use the shorter version of connection string when a parent/child is set. I'm using the python SDK----I did resolve my DNS too however there's no way of knowing if the data is just going through the direct IOT HUB connection ignoring the gatewayHostname parameter or if its utilizing the gatewayHostName parameter and sending it via gateway)

Comment: The Edge Hub supports a shorter connection string but the SDK also needs to support it, and I'm not sure all the SDKs do. Sounds like Python might not, in particular.

Comment: Yeap, clearly. The python one doesn't as it raises errors. Besides it sucks how they don't have any API reference or documentation for Python SDK.(My stack's python/C/JS). I either have to go through uncommented C code on their repository to find my way around OR I can just switch to an SDK that's well documented(I've been looking .Net one, so far so good- I've migrated to dotNet). Really wish they'd do something about the documentation/references for python SDK

Answer (score 0):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-connect-downstream-device#troubleshoot-the-gateway-connection

[image]

Sounds like 1) and 2) might be exactly your issue. The hostname you set in config.yaml needs to resolve to the proper IP

Comment: Yes, I understand that the hostname isn't resolvable from my leaf device(I've tried pinging it. It's a DNS issue probably.) It is for these reasons that I ended up entering the IP address since entering the hostname in connection string would give some entirely different connection errors. Does it HAVE to be a string hostname? I mean, at the end of day, the hostname being resolvable to an IP address should be the same as entering that IP Address. No? 

I will be looking into the DNS but I highly doubt this is causing the problem. Is there anything else you think I'm missing out?

Comment: I just edited with an update. Could you check and shed some light?

Comment: The certificated generated is with hostname "edgeuser-virtual-machine" instead of the ip address right? Thus the certificate validation failed.